# How to use torch quantization on the float values to reduce the number of bits from FP64 to 8 bits?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, precision, quantization

I'm trying to reduce the precision of floating point values using quantization libraries from the *torch.quantization* module ([quantization link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.quantize_per_tensor.html)).
My sample array is written in numpy and here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.quantization
dtype = torch.qint8
test1 = np.array([0.23999573, 0.04214323, 0.03814219, 0.13811627, 0.5416026])
print(test1)
print(test1.dtype)

t = torch.from_numpy(test1)
print(t)
print(t.dtype)
t.to(dtype=dtype)
```

I first convert the vector into torch tensors and then I try to import all the quantization libraries and change the precision to *torch.qint8*.
Error I get:

```
[0.23999573 0.04214323 0.03814219 0.13811627 0.5416026 ]
float64
tensor([0.2400, 0.0421, 0.0381, 0.1381, 0.5416], dtype=torch.float64)
torch.float64

    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
    
    <ipython-input-17-7ac6609713a1> in <cell line: 22>()
         20 print(t)
         21 print(t.dtype)
    ---> 22 t.to(dtype=dtype)
    
    RuntimeError: empty_strided not supported on quantized tensors yet see https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/74540
```

My default array is in numpy and the standard code is written in tensorflow. I converted the array to torch because I did not find any quantization libraries that can convert to lower precision and save the storage space.

I was thinking whether there's a library which implements the lower precision data types like Float16 or 8 bits by numpy which I could use.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Extra question: In many research papers, I observed that the number of bits can be reduced to 8 bits or even lower until 2 bits on neural networks. Is there any way that we can take existing vector and reduce the number of bits for each floating point number (apply quantization on the data) to lower bits such as 4 bits, 2 bits etc.

Reference paper: [Quatization paper](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=xwWsiFmUEs) (page-20 in the paper)